# Asserting that only some specific attributes of an object are not null

Tags: java, junit

We have a test method which calls a method which in turn gives back a collection(List).
More than asserting that the List is not empty we need to take each Object from the List and ensure that specific attributes of the List are not null.

We are already doing it in  a for loop like this :

```
testMethod() {

    List<Person> list = dao.getPersons();

    for(Person person: list) {
        assertTrue("Firstname cant be null",person.getFirstName());
        assertTrue("Address line 1 cant be null",person.getAddress1());
    }

    //Requesting advise on the best approach that would suit this.

}
```

Thanks
Venu

Comment: You should assertNotnull instead. If you want some syntactic sugar you could use google-guava instead.

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. Java doesn't do type coercion like Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use the method [`assertNotNull`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertNotNull%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to ensure that an object is not null. but you still need to loop through your list.

```
testMethod() {
    List<Person> list = dao.getPersons();
    for(Person person: list) {
        assertNotNull("Firstname cant be null", person.getFirstName());
        assertNotNull("Address line 1 cant be null", person.getAddress1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   testMethod() {
        List<Person> list = dao.getPersons();

        for(Person person: list) {
            assertNotNull("Firstname cant be null",person.getFirstName());
            assertNotNull("Address line 1 cant be null",person.getAddress1());
        } 
    }
```

If specific attributes isn't allowed to be null, then maybe you should refactor your code in a null safe manner so `null` values can't be inserted. I mean if they're not allowed to be null why would it be possibel to set them null?